# Custom test of http header with spring-test-mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-test-mvc

I'm testing my MVC service with `spring-test-mvc` I used something like:

```
MockMvc mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller).build();
mockMvc.perform(get("<my-url>")).andExpect(content().bytes(expectedBytes)).andExpect(content().type("image/png"))
       .andExpect(header().string("cache-control", "max-age=3600"));
```

Which worked fine.

Now I changed the cache image to be random in a specific range. For example, instead of `3600` it could be `3500-3700`. I'm trying to figure out how I can get the header value and do some tests on it instead of using this pattern of `andExpect`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Perhaps you mean something like this.

```
    MvcResult mvcResult = mvc.perform(get("/")).andReturn();
    String headerValue = mvcResult.getResponse().getHeader("headerName");
```

Answer (score 12):

The best way is `MockMvcResultMatchers.header()` of spring-test

```
mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api"))
.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.header()
.stringValues("count", "150"));
```

Answer (score 3):

To add a little more detail to Admit's answer: if you also have access to a JAX-RS implementation in your code, you can use the CacheControl object to make a very explicit test (example using hamcrest matchers):

```
int maxAge = CacheControl
                .valueOf(mvcResult.getResponse().getHeader("Cache-Control"))
                .getMaxAge();

assertThat(maxAge, is(both(greaterThanOrEqualTo(3500)).and(lessThanOrEqualTo(3700))));
```